# Receive Facebook notifications for Likes on my website?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-insights

I have my portfolio at http://visualise.ca and I would like to receive Facebook notifications (within Facebook) when a visitor does a Like on one of my photo.

1) Is that possible?

I was looking at the FB.Event.subscribe documentation, but I'm not sure.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

2) If not possible do you have any suggestions on how I could receive some type of instant notifications anyhow?

The information I would need would be :
- The URL liked
- The Facebook user ID of the "Liker" or his profile page url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) yes, subscribe to the `edge.create` event and then AJAX to your server the information you want to store.  Facebook Id will ONLY be available to you if that user has previously authenticated to your app.

2) it's possible, so no answer for #2.

Comment: OK so I added FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) { SOME CODE HERE }); and notify="true" and it should work? Could you please Like a photo on my site please to test.

Comment: I'm unable to make it work and have created a specific question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254388/receiving-notifications-for-the-facebook-like-button-on-my-website